# Bokeh Plots: Appending plots to existing file

Tags: python, bokeh

I need to append plots based on different functions to same .HTML output file. I believe `output_file` is causing this to happen. How can I plot figures using multiple functions but to same file?

**Function1:**

```
def tuplesplot4(tuplessent_df,miscplot_name,tracer):
    try:
        with tracer.start_as_current_span("miscellaneous_plot"):
            span = trace.get_current_span()
            span.set_attribute("method","tuplesplot4")

            output_file(miscplot_name,'Misc Plots')
            datetime_tick_formats = {
                    key: ["%a %b %d %H:%M:%S"]
                    for key in ("seconds", "minsec", "minutes", "hourmin", "hours", "days")}

            source_tuplessent = ColumnDataSource(tuplessent_df.sort_values(by=['log_time']))

            hover0 = HoverTool(tooltips = [("Date","@log_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"),("Value:","@tuples_time")],formatters = {'@log_time':'datetime'})
            p0 = figure(title='Time to send Tuples',plot_width=1000,plot_height=400,x_axis_type='datetime')
            p0.xaxis.axis_label="Time"
            p0.yaxis.axis_label="ms"
            p0.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(**datetime_tick_formats)
            p0.line(x='log_time',y='tuples_time',source=source_tuplessent,line_width=2,color="red")

            p0.add_tools(hover0)

            hover1 = HoverTool(tooltips = [("Date","@log_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"),("Value:","@tuples_cnt")],formatters = {'@log_time':'datetime'})
            p1 = figure(title='# of Tuples',plot_width=1000,plot_height=400,x_axis_type='datetime')
            p1.xaxis.axis_label="Time"
            p1.yaxis.axis_label="#"
            p1.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(**datetime_tick_formats)
            p1.line(x='log_time',y='tuples_cnt',source=source_tuplessent,line_width=2,color="red")

            p1.add_tools(hover1)

            plot = column(p0,p1)
            save(plot)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**Function2:**

```
def collectorsduration4(collectors_times_df,miscplot_name,tracer):
    try:
       with tracer.start_as_current_span("miscellaneous_plot"):
            span = trace.get_current_span()
            span.set_attribute("method","collectorsduration4")

            output_file(miscplot_name,'Misc Plots')
            datetime_tick_formats = {
                    key: ["%a %b %d %H:%M:%S"]
                    for key in ("seconds", "minsec", "minutes", "hourmin", "hours", "days")}

            time2wifi_df = collectors_times_df.query('collector_type == "wifi_info_collector" and component == "wifi"')
            source_time2wifi = ColumnDataSource(time2wifi_df.sort_values(by=['log_time']))
            hover0 = HoverTool(tooltips = [("Date","@log_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"),("Value:","@time")],formatters = {'@log_time':'datetime'})
            p0 = figure(title='Total Time - WIFI Info',plot_width=1000,plot_height=400,x_axis_type='datetime')
            p0.xaxis.axis_label="Time"
            p0.yaxis.axis_label="ms"
            p0.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(**datetime_tick_formats)
            p0.line(x='log_time',y='time',source=source_time2wifi,line_width=2,color="red")

            p0.add_tools(hover0)
            plot = column(p0,p1,p2)
            save(plot)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

In my `main` function I call the above 2 functions.

```
miscplot.tuplesplot4(tuplessent_df,miscplot_name,tracer)
miscplot.collectorsduration4(collectors_times_df,miscplot_name,tracer)
```

Looks like this is causing plots to be overwritten. I need all plots in the same file. I could pass both my DataFrames to same function, but I guess it is bad coding practice to have such huge line of code in one function??

Comment: `save` writes a new file, full stop. There are no Bokeh APIs for extending existing HTML files (seems like a very fragile thing to want to try).  It seems like your functions should *return* the plot objects (instead of saving them to files) then whatever calls both functions at a higher level can save all the plots in a layout.

Comment: @bigreddot Awesome! Thank you again! Now I am returning my figures mentioned in above code (p0,p1,p2..). Created another function which takes this as input and does the plotting. Now I have all plots in same HTML.

Thank you very much!